# Feed ticker Facebook API JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ticker

I want to get the ticker of facebook to display in my website but I can't see API for javascript in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/).

Anyone can show me how I can get ticker Facebook by JS?

Thanks.